# impossible to use vue-multiseclect in symfony-ux-vue

Tags: symfony, vuejs3, vue-multiselect, symfonyux

I have a little problem, I can't use vue-multiselect or their equivalent in my vuejs component in symfony-ux-vue. I find myself running into the following problem
[image: error from my browser]

I have to review the imports even in the main script like app.js or boostrap.js but nothing